# Adding padding to QLabel in PyQt

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt6

I dont know if I am making a mistake or I am trying to do something that doesnt even exist.

I am having a QLabel, and I added any text to it. I want to have some padding between the label and the text. So I would obviously use the padding in stylesheet. However it is not working as expected. Here is the code:

```py
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication , QMainWindow , QLabel
from PyQt6.QtGui import QColor

app = QApplication([])

window = QMainWindow()

# Main card
card = QLabel(window)

card.setStyleSheet("""padding: 10px; background-color: green""")

card.setText("ndfnjdfnjdnfjnjnjnj")

window.show()

app.exec()
```

Here, I expected some padding between the text and the border (and thought that the width and height would increase as it does in html).

But I get this output:

[image: Output]

It happens totally opposite.

Comment: First of all, you should not add child widgets to QMainWindow, as widgets that are not part of menu/status/dock/toolbars are to be used inside a *central widget* (using `setCentralWidget()`. The question is: what do you expect as result? The text in the middle, and the green all around it?

Comment: As I stated, I wanted the text to be in middle, with some padding around the text

Comment: "Some padding" is a vague concept: the padding completely depends on the surrounding widget. Also remember that while QSS are based on CSS2.1, they don't work exactly in the same way and only support properties specific for that version (and not even all of them). That said: just use `setCentralWidget` as explained above, and specify the text alignment in the label. But that won't be enough: after that you'll probably need to add other things, so I strongly suggest you to read more about [layout managers](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) and also remember to avoid generic properties in QSS.

Comment: Thanks! I would look into it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Are you maybe looking for `margin` instead of `padding`? Like:

```
card.setStyleSheet("""margin: 10px; background-color: green""")
```